# Looping over the non-zero elements of a uBlas sparse matrix

Tags: c++, boost, sparse-matrix, ublas

I have the following sparse matrix that contains `O(N)` elements

```
boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_matrix<int> adjacency (N, N);
```

I could write a brute force double loop to go over all the entries in `O(N^2)` time like below, but this is going to be too slow.

```
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
   for(int j=0; j<N; ++j)
       std::cout << adjacency(i,j) std::endl;
```

How can I loop over only the non-zero entries in `O(N)` time? For each non-zero element I would like to have access to its value, and the indexes `i,j`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find the answer in this FAQ: [How to iterate over all non zero elements?](http://www.guwi17.de/ublas/matrix_sparse_usage.html#Q1)

In your case it would be:

```
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_matrix<int>::iterator1 it1_t;
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_matrix<int>::iterator2 it2_t;

for (it1_t it1 = adjacency.begin1(); it1 != adjacency.end1(); it1++)
{
  for (it2_t it2 = it1.begin(); it2 != it1.end(); it2++)
  {
    std::cout << "(" << it2.index1() << "," << it2.index2() << ") = ";
    std::cout << *it2 << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Important note which I forgot to add: the type of storage organization you choose for a compressed matrix matters, because it decides what the fastest way of iterating the compressed matrix will be. If you have row_major as storage type, my example above is the fastest way to iterate. If you choose column_major, you will have to exchange the inner and outer loop, i.e. looping over the columns first will be the fastest.

Comment: boost will iterate depending on the storage representation (row-major or col-major). So the same loops above will work for either representation. No changes need to be made.

Comment: Sorry for bumping an old post. I'm not sure this code actually works see http://lists.boost.org/MailArchives/ublas/2006/11/1516.php. From my experience it will iterate over every element.