# Why do I get a numeric::ublas::bad_index error when iterating on the elements of a sparse matrix?

Tags: c++, boost, ublas

I am using the Boost library, version 1.44.0 and c++ with gcc 4.0.

I have created a `ublas::compressed_matrix<double>` and I have filled it using the method `insert_element(index1, index2, value)`.
Thereafter I am iterating through the elements of the matrix and printing out the non-zero elements. I use the following code for iterating (note that `i1_t` and `i2_t` are `typedef boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_matrix<double>::iterator`):

```
   for (i1_t i1 = matrix->begin1(); i1 != matrix->end1(); i1++) {
    for (i2_t i2 = matrix->begin2(); i2 != matrix->end2(); i2++) {
     cout<<"("<<i2.index1()<<","<<i2.index2()<<")="<<*i2<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
   }
```

Or alternatively the following:

```
    for (i1_t i1 = matrix->begin1(); i1 != matrix->end1(); i1++) {
    cout<<i1.index1()<<" -> ";
    for (i2_t i2 = matrix->begin2(); i2 != matrix->end2(); i2++) {
     cout<<i2.index2()<<" ("<<*i2<<") ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
   }
```

Of course, both of them are doing pretty much the same thing. The code follows the suggestions provided by another post in stackoverflow: [iterating on non-zero elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795658/looping-over-the-non-zero-elements-of-a-ublas-sparse-matrix)

However, when running the code, I get that only the first few elements are correctly printed (in particular, this applies to the first six entries), until I get the following error:

```
Check failed in file /opt/local/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp at line 3109:
p
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::numeric::ublas::bad_index'
  what():  bad index
```

All the elements, however, seem to be correctly inserted into the matrix.
I am wondering what is going on, why I get this error and what does it mean?

Many thanks.

Comment: I suspect you may have edited out the cause of your problem by putting in an edited version of your loop. Can you post complete code that fails so we can reproduce a test-case?

Comment: Hi Kieveli, thanks for your attention. The instruction that generates the error is requesting the element that is pointed by the inner iterator (*i2), nested within the two for loops. In fact i2.index2() is always correctly performed, while *i2 generates an error after you have accessed few elements. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what the problem was, and of course it was my mistake on the code.

In fact the inner loop (i.e. the second for loop) iterates through the wrong thing. Originally I wrote:

```
for (i2_t i2 = matrix->begin2(); i2 != matrix->end2(); i2++)
```

However, `i2` should not iterate from `matrx->begin2()` to `matrix->end2()`. Instead, the limits of the iteration for `i2` should be `i1.begin()` and `i1.end()`, where `i1` is the first iterator! Apologies for my mistake.

So, to summarise, the correct loop should be:

```
for (i1_t i1 = matrix->begin1(); i1 != matrix->end1(); i1++) {
   for (i2_t i2 = i1.begin(); i2 != i1.end(); i2++) {
      cout << "(" << i2.index1() << "," << i2.index2() << ")=" << *i2 << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```